# How to send transaction to Infura node using Web3?

Tags: web3js, transactions, ether, myetherwallet, infura

I want to send ETH from one account to another using Web3 interface and Infura node. I have tried like below, and I got error 405(). Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

I test it in Rinkeby test network.
This is how I initialize Web3 and do the transaction.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            const Web3 = require('web3');
            const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/<Access_Token>'));

            $(".btn-send").click(function () {
                web3.eth.sendTransaction(
                    {
                        to: '0xae8cE2D0B2015Aeb62189822C7eEae2f60B011e5',
                        from: '0x5ada788989dCa813cBE82eD8bB8d54e1b43327A7',
                        value: web3.toWei("1", "ether")
                    },
                    function (error, transactionHash) {
                        if (!error) {
                            console.log("send successfully");
                        } else {
                            console.log("Error: " + error);
                        }
                    }
                );
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: you need to sign the transaction

Answer (score 4):

A 405 error means that the underlying JSON-RPC method is not supported by Infura. Infura only blocks methods that do not make sense for Infura, such as those that require Infura to store private keys. Apparently `web3.eth.sendTransaction` invokes the `eth_sendTransaction` method (which requires the server to hold keys). You need to use the web3 method that instead invokes `eth_sendRawTransaction`, so that the transaction signing happens locally.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use your personnal parity/geth node to create offline transaction. and after that you can send this transaction with infura.
documentation link : [how to send transaction with infura web3js](http://web3j.readthedocs.io/en/stable/infura.html#transactions)